# Bug with shape keys (morph targets) in specific environment: React-Three-Fiber, GLTFJSX,

Tags: animation, modifiers, gltf, three.js, surface-deform

Hey Blender community!

Thank you in advance for your time and for helping me learn.

I'm having a lasting issue with morph targets. I would deeply appreciate advice from someone more experienced. The model is of gums/teeth , and the shape keys (morph targets) are intended to adapt the gums for a baby tooth or an adult tooth. The problem is that activating any of the morph targets on the upper gums causes the gums to be spiked (see photo). Here are some observed features:

1. **The lower gums morph targets work perfectly as expected!** Most perplexing.
2. **The upper gums morph targets work in other environments. The environment where the spikes occur utilizes [react-three-fiber](https://github.com/pmndrs/react-three-fiber) + [gltfjsx](https://github.com/pmndrs/gltfjsx)**
3. If left unmorphed in its original state (all influences at 0), the gums look smooth. As soon as any of the 16 upper morph targets are applied, the spikes appear. At the same time, applying the lower morph targets works perfectly as expected.
4. The model is being exported from Blender 3.5 as a .glb. Compression of the .glb does not appear to be the cause.
   I have uploaded a version of the gums [.blend file to google drive,](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FjbOhH1ulIbzU9y6DJeN0oGxnpu0v8Le/view?usp=drive_link) and would greatly appreciate it if anyone could help me learn/investigate why the lower gums work, but not the upper!
   I greatly appreciate your support and helping me learn.

All my best,
Hudson S

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "morph target"? The only mention I can see in Blender might be another name for shape keys, but your question appears to be talking about external software which is off-topic here.

Comment: Hey @JohnEason , thank you for your reply. I'm sorry, my terminology may not be precise. You're correct, the morph targets are created with shape keys. The external software is just the three.js renderer; because the lower gums work there, I'm assuming the problem is related to my blend file?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  That upper gum has almost 24000 duplicate vertices! In Edit mode, select All then hit M > Merge > By Distance and watch the centre of the bottom status bar where the number of vertices removed will be shown briefly. The lower gum **only** has 11000 duplicates... Not sure whether this will cure your problem but it's worth a try. I've not used shape keys much but suspect that you may have to set them again after you've removed the duplicates.

Comment: Very interesting that the issue occurs only in react-three-fiber + gltfjsx... Could you share the gltfjsx command you're running? It has some compression of its own with the `--transform` flag, which could be relevant here... if that modifies the file, does the modified file also work fine in viewers? This looks a lot like a data precision issue to me.

Comment: @JohnEason Woah! Thank you, John! Your suggestion to remove the duplicate vertices has completely solved the problem. Furthermore, the shape keys seem largely unchanged. Impressive! Thank you so much for your help. How did you track down that issue?

Comment: @DonMcCurdy great idea! The command I used was *npx gltfjsx MixedDentition2.0.glb --types --keepnames* However; as I iterate on the model I am no longer running the command. I am writing over the .glb with Blender export. Perhaps it is a data precision issue in that the react-three-fiber was choosing different vertices to morph than other renderers due to the sheer number of duplicates. Maybe it has a compression of its own as well? I'm not sure, this was an interesting error presentation to learn from. Thank you deeply for your support and for helping me learn.

Comment: @HudsonSpangler I've seen so many issues with duplicate verts causing problems that it's always the first thing I try  when I see a Blend file with any sort of animation problems. Good to hear that you didn't have to redo the shape keys!